# Python raising error when user input is blank

Tags: python

I've just started learning classes in Python and I've got a question on how to react to user's input.

```
class Test:
  def __init__(self, a=0, b=0):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
```

If user inputs:

```
>> t = Test()
>> t.a
0
>> t.b
0
```

then it is fine, because variables a and b are initially 0.

If user inputs:

```
>> t = Test(0, 0)
>> t.a
0
>> t.b
0
```

then it is also fine, because the user did input two variables.

But if user inputs:

```
>> t = Test(0)
```

then I want to raise an error such as "TestError: Cannot ...", since the user has given only one variable.

How can I check the user's input..?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. EDIT: Yeah I misread your post.

Comment: @FarhoodET it's not a problem, it's something OP wants to implement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the default values as `None`, and then check to see if the user has passed in another value:

```
class TestError(Exception): 
    pass


class Test:
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        if (a is not None and b is None or
            a is None and b is not None):
            raise TestError
        self.a = a if a is not None else 0
        self.b = b if b is not None else 0


t = Test()      # works
t = Test(0, 0)  # works
t = Test(0)     # raises TestError
```

Now, of course, you could run into the edge case when the user decides to initialize your class as `Test(None)`, because we can't tell which of those `None` values came from the default values and which were passed in by the user.

If that's an issue, we can take advantage of the fact that Python evaluates default arguments once, and use a mutable object to check if it's the same object (using `is` for identity checking) as the one passed in by the user:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a=[], b=[]):
        a_default, b_default = self.__init__.__defaults__
        if (a is not a_default and b is b_default or
            a is a_default and b is not b_default):
            raise TestError
        self.a = a if a is not a_default else 0
        self.b = b if b is not b_default else 0
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if `None` is an intended value to be passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Well if `b` is a required value, it should not have a default.

But you can achieve something similar, you can redesign your class a bit:

```
class Test:
   def __init__(self, *args):
      if len(args) < 2:
         raise Exception('TestError')
      self.a = args[0]
      self.b = args[1]

t = Test(0)
```

This causes:

```
Exception: TestError
```

But obviously this is much less readable.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 0:
            a = 0
            b = 0
        elif len(args) == 2:
            a, b = args
        else:
            raise TypeError("incorrect number of arguments")

        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

Basically it's giving you the exact argument list, and letting you decide which argument counts are valid.  So the following will work:

```
t = Test()
t = Test(0, 0)
```

while the following will raise exceptions:

```
t = Test(0)
t = Test(0, 0, 0)
```